CreateProcess() Elevation problem and solution to UAC (C++)
I have a quite challenging task in C++ to run a different program inside my own program, but there's a difficulty: my program should be running both as user and as admin, but the next program, which is launching inside mine, should be asking for admin rights and elevation (UAC).
The main goal is to get the output from launching program to mine (it's parent).
Is there any way to create process with elevation and get an output from that process?
Thank you for any answers I can get!
In WinApi there are two ways to launch a process inside a process:

CreateProcess()
ShellExcecute()

I tried both of them, but:

CreateProcess() normally creates a process with the same privileges as its parent program, so when I tried launching it from user without admin rights, it fails with error 740 (can't create a process, which is requiring elevation).
ShellExecute() works fine and asks for elevation, but has no output from launched program to mine (it only returns a value to indicate error/no error).


Does this answer your question? Explicit ShellExecute without elevated rights

Duplicate of Start elevated subprocess from C++ code and communicate with it via stdin/stdout and C++: Communication with elevated child process on Windows (neither of which have answers posted, so can't close this question as a duplicate of them).

What type of data are you sharing from the elevated sub-process back to the parent process?  Is it a continuous stream of data?  Periodic events?  Single blob of result data?  Just an exit code (integer)?  Something else?  Will the parent process send more messages or commands to the child process after it starts?

By now I'm trying to get a console output from program of sentinel key conversion (not very important) - reads key and gives strings of text like "Succesfully converted key №..." - for me it's just a plain text, which I can parse inside mine program to continue. Because of a UAC, which requires elevation, it's not possible to use pipes and CreateProcess()
Despite that I already done such things: found that some person in 2008 created CreateProcessElevated() and I succeeded in uisng it (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide), but author didn't give sources

Also tried ShellExecuteEx() with parametrs to console like " > c:/results/results.txt -p [password]", but I think it doesn't redirect an output from console to txt, because of the same UAC elevation problem.
